# Find Maximum of Lower Envelope

Tags: convex-optimization, linear-programming

Okay, I'm not really sure whether the title is good. Consider

\begin{align*}
  \min\{
  5x_1 + \frac{5}{2}x_2 + \frac{5}{3}x_3 + \frac{5}{4}x_4, \\
  x_1 + \frac{6}{2}x_2 + \frac{6}{3}x_3 + \frac{6}{4}x_4, \\
  x_1 + x_2 + \frac{7}{3}x_3 + \frac{7}{4}x_4, \\
  x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + 2x_4\}.
\end{align*}

Moreover, I have the restrictions $0 \le x_i \le 1$ and $\sum x_i = 1$. I want to maximize the above term by choosing the $x_i$ appropriately. How can I show that the optimal choice is the one that sets the four terms equal (i.e., $x_1 = 25 / 369, x_2 = 40 / 369, x_3 = 48 / 369, x_4 = 256 / 369$)?

I have read about linear programming, the lower envelope, convex optimization, piecewise-linear functions—but I cannot quite put all of this together. Can anyone give me a hint in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

Since you just want a hint, I'll just walk through how you can reformulate this an LP. First note that the constraints $x_i \le 1$ are redundant, since nonnegative numbers which sum to 1 cannot be greater than 1. Then using vector notation the problem can be stated as:
$$
\begin{gathered}
\max_{\mathbf{x}} \ \min_i \mathbf{a}_i^T  \mathbf{x} \\
\text{s.t.: }
\mathbf{x}^T \mathbf{1} = 1 \\
\mathbf{x} \ge 0
\end{gathered}
$$
Then we can introduce another variable $y$ without changing the problem:
$$
\begin{gathered}
\max_{\mathbf{x}, y} \ y \\
\text{s.t.: } \min_i \mathbf{a}_i^T \mathbf{x} \ge y\\
\mathbf{x}^T \mathbf{1} = 1 \\
\mathbf{x} \ge 0
\end{gathered}
$$
Then this is equivalent to the LP:
$$
\begin{gathered}
\max_{\mathbf{x}, y} y \\
\text{s.t.: } \mathbf{a}_i^T \mathbf{x} \ge y \text{ for } i=1\ldots4\\
\mathbf{x}^T \mathbf{1} = 1 \\
\mathbf{x} \ge 0
\end{gathered}
$$
In matrix notation this is:
$$
\begin{gathered}
\max_{\mathbf{x}, y} y \\
\text{s.t.: } \mathbf{Ax} \ge y \mathbf{1}\\
\mathbf{x}^T \mathbf{1} = 1 \\
\mathbf{x} \ge 0
\end{gathered}
$$
Lastly, if you want to put this in standard form, you can introduce a slack variable. Also, it doesn't hurt to assume $y \ge 0$.
$$
\begin{gathered}
\max_{\mathbf{x}, y, \mathbf{z}} y \\
\text{s.t.: } \mathbf{Ax} = y \mathbf{1} + \mathbf{z}\\
\mathbf{x}^T \mathbf{1} = 1 \\
\mathbf{x}\ge 0, y\ge0, \mathbf{z} \ge 0
\end{gathered}
$$
Finally, expressed in standard form with block matrices we have:
$$
\begin{gathered}
\max_{\mathbf{x}, y, \mathbf{z}} \ 
\begin{bmatrix} \mathbf{0} \\ 1 \\\mathbf{0}\end{bmatrix}^T
\begin{bmatrix} \mathbf{x} \\ y \\\mathbf{z}\end{bmatrix}
 \\
\text{s.t.: } 
\begin{bmatrix} A & -\mathbf{1} & -\mathbf{I} \\ 
\mathbf{1}^T & 0 & \mathbf{0}^T
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix} \mathbf{x} \\ y \\\mathbf{z}\end{bmatrix}
 = \begin{bmatrix} \mathbf{0} \\ 1  \end{bmatrix}\\
\begin{bmatrix} \mathbf{x} \\ y \\\mathbf{z}
\end{bmatrix} \ge 0
\end{gathered}
$$
Your problem is then reduced to showing that the optimal solution to this LP has $\mathbf{z}=0$.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'm sure that helps. Unfortunately, I don't have time at the moment to look at it.